# How to connect a bulb and buzzer to be operated by one switch?

Tags: circuit-design

I want to make a simple circuit. I want to connect a bulb, buzzer and switch to a battery. About the size we all used in science at school. When the switch is on, I want the buzzer and bulb to work together. Do I need to use resistors and transistors? I have no idea. Help!

Comment: "Work together" meaning turn on at the same time? That would be a parallel bulb+buzzer, with a series switch. Certainly no need for anything else.

Answer (score 8):

You eventually need a lot more information in order to get an answer to this, but with the optimistic assumption that both the bulb and buzzer operate from the same voltage as the battery...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8BL8K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Best that can be done given the input data.  If using an LED instead of a bulb you need a suitably rated device or a current limiting series resistor.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using a readymade buzzer**, there is **no** need to buy transistors etc (an internal oscillator, containing a coil, a transistor and few resistors already given in that buzzer), **and the circuit you're trying to make, is very simple**.

[image: Circuit buzzer light]

### The only-thing you have to keep in notice, that, electric current goes through the wire just like water flows through pipe. The batteries work like pump. one end of the battery (+ve end) pumps-out the positive charges, and the other-end of the battery, sucks-in the positive-charge. Keeping-it in mind , you can alter the placement of parts, make a **"circuit" or a complete circular path** , and test the circuit is working or not.

### Important notes

**If you're using a readymade buzzer**,

keep in mind, it contains 2 wires, of different nature (polarity). Red wire is positive input to buzzer, black-one is negative-input to buzzer.

---

**LED vs Bulb ?**

LED is a kind of semiconductor-diode that gives light when in forward bias. it is not bulb in true-sense. however,
LEDs are now being used widely, since they're durable and cheap. But LEDs have polarity.

[image: LED STRUCTURE wikipedia]
picture of an LED

[image: led symbol wikipedia]
symbol of  LED

Anode is the positive input pole, and cathode is the negative input pole.

You could also use small bulbs (**torch bulbs**), but they are nowadays rare in market.

[image: bulb image ekshiksha]

Bulbs need **no** specific polarity

but usually, torch-bulbs have one end at bottom, and other end at side, shown in the image.
http://www.ekshiksha.org.in/images%20of%20Electricity_and_Circuits_VI/3.png

bulb symbol
[image: bulb symbol]

**Batteries**

You could take 1.5Volt or 3Volt batteries in different numbers, all in series combination, to adjust voltage. usually an LED cuts-open before 7.5V or 12V, however in a series or parallel combination , the LED gets lesser voltage from the same source, so needs quite higher voltage. A readymade piezo-buzzer is usually loud enough,. so I guess three or four 1.5V batteries maybe enough.

See also:http://www.ekshiksha.org.in/eContent-Show.do?documentId=51

Comment: @ Passerby Thanks so much for adjustment of image size. how to do that?

Comment: I had done that, but there is not enough juice for the light. It slowly turns on, but not bright at all. The bell works as expected. Should I change the transformer (higher voltage)? The original circuit was just for the bell, my friend is deaf and cannot hear the  bell. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: @user2060451 You are using a "battery", then why you would need any transformer? "Slowly turns on" sounds like you are using some-other parts that you have not mentioned in original post.

Comment: in my case, it is a house bell. I would like to add a light bulb for a hearing-impaired person. I put them in line and parallel. Does not work. I believe I need to get a higher transformer in order to have more power. I didn't want to deal with the transformer though.... @always confused

Comment: @user2060451 Please specify all the changes to your question. As well as SE is not designed to be a discussion forum but a site for permanent preservation of question and answer. So a frequent change in the original meaning of a question can draw objection from moderators. Okay I'll be update my answer few weeks latter b'coz I'm extremely busy with a competitive exam. In the mean time you could discuss your queries in chat room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering), a friendly place.